# How to match trained image with multiple query images in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, sift

I would like to design an image processing program where it detects and matches hand gestures. What I basically need to do is matching a query image with multiple trained images and returning the best match. 
Below code is the implementation of two single hand gestures.

```
import cv2 as cv

sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
bf = cv.BFMatcher()

original_img = cv.imread('./database/bb.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
query_img = cv.imread('./database/b.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

kp1,des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original_img , None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(query_img ,None)

matches = bf.knnMatch( des1, des2, k=2 )
good = []

for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good.append ( [m] )

new_img = cv.drawMatchesKnn(original_img, kp1, query_img, kp2, good, None, flags=2)
cv.imshow('matches' , new_img)

k = cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed OpenCV3 and the code needs to score for each match. This is the link for
[Match each pair of images using opencv3](https://github.com/bryanibit/pySfM/blob/3b643f45d1dbf797c5f24a18d022b5954988e757/detect_features.py#L141). 
Use the above function, you could get the matches for features of each pair of images.
Of course, you need to evaluate the matches and give each match a score, then sort them. I think the link [Score for each match](https://github.com/bryanibit/pySfM/blob/3b643f45d1dbf797c5f24a18d022b5954988e757/reconstruct.py#L59) could help you.